# List in asp.net linq query not working

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
  const string keyword = "manoj";
        rsp.DataSource = company.GetCompanySearch(keyword);
        rsp.DataBind();

    public List<Company> GetCompanySearch(string keyword)
{
    using (var context = huntableEntities.GetEntitiesWithNoLock())
    {
        List<Company> query = context.Companies.ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            keyword = keyword.ToLower();
            query =  (List<Company>) query.Where(u=>u.CompanyName.Contains(keyword)
                                           || u.EmailAdress.Contains(keyword)
                                           ||u.MasterCountry.Description.Contains(keyword)
                                           ||u.MasterIndustry.Description.Contains(keyword)
                                           ||u.CompanyDescription.Contains(keyword)
                                           ||u.CompanyHeading.Contains(keyword));
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

The following code throwing the following exception:
{"Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Data.Company]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.Company]'."}

Comment: the error message explained; You can't convert `WhereListIterator` to `List` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(List) query.Where()" is equal to "(List) (query.Where())", so this will throw  that exception.
Should use query.Where().ToList() but not a explicit cast.

Further, better not put "List query = context.Companies.ToList();" before your "if" statement. In this case, no matter keyword is empty or not, it will query all records into memory and it will cause performance problem.
Can change to below

```
    IQueryable<Company> query = context.Companies; //Remove ToList()
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        keyword = keyword.ToLower();
        // Remove cast
        query =  query.Where(u=>u.CompanyName.Contains(keyword)
                                       || u.EmailAdress.Contains(keyword)
                                       ||u.MasterCountry.Description.Contains(keyword)
                                       ||u.MasterIndustry.Description.Contains(keyword)
                                       ||u.CompanyDescription.Contains(keyword)
                                       ||u.CompanyHeading.Contains(keyword));
    }
    return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it is working..But can you explain the reason mine query is  not working and difference of Iquerable and list

Comment: @ManojChowdary The reason why your query not working is the explicit cast. "(List) query.Where()" is trying to cast "query.Where()" to "List", it will throw exception, because not able to explicitly cast type "WhereListIterator" to type "List", just as the exception message said.

Comment: @ManojChowdary IQueryable make the query "lazy loading". It will not read database unless you call a "Count", "ToList", "AsEnumerable", or "foreach".  "ToList" will cause a immediate database query. In your original coding, even if keyword is not empty, the statement "ToList" will query all companies from database to memory, then the "Where" filtering will be run in memory. So performance it's not good here.